# Check dates when marking "exact duplicates"

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

We should check dates on questions marked as duplicates -- specific example:

(Question 1) [How to read all recurring events from share point calendar list using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189656/how-to-read-all-recurring-events-from-share-point-calendar-list-using-javascript/189702#189702) - asked August 4 2016 @ 1525 GMT

(Question 2) [how to read all recurrance events from sp calendar list in SP hosted app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189756/how-to-read-all-recurrance-events-from-sp-calendar-list-in-sp-hosted-app) - asked August 5 2016 @ 1001 GMT

Question 1 then marked as Duplicate of Question 2 August 5 2016 @ 2045 GMT

I provided an answer to the closed one; I don't necessarily feel wronged - just that, as a matter of procedure, I think we should prefer the first-asked question when determining duplicate closures.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for enlighting this, John. I've merged the questions making your answer available on the open question.

In terms of closing questions, there are different opinions on how this should be performed. On one hand the one that posted the question first should be open, and all other duplicates closed. Another way to see this is the better asked question should stay open. Which way to chose is up to the community, but I tend to lean toward first asked should stay open.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And sometimes we just aren't as vigilant as we should be when processing flags, apologies for that.